# GCC/Clang. If some -O flags are optimal in a certain machine, they will be also optimal in another machine?

Tags: gcc, optimization, clang

I am looking for the optimal optimizations flags to my specific code. By googling for a while, I found that there are not a golden rule to choose optimal optimizations. *The answer depends on the specific code, compiler and machine*.

The recommended optimization flag is `-O2`, although in certain cases  `-Os` (in order to generate a smaller binary) could produce binary with faster executions. I  prefer to ignore the use of `-O3` and superior optimizations because in some situations it could be dangerous. In some cases combine `-O2` with `-Os` flags produce better results. Or in other situations compilations with `-march=native` give a optimized binary for the specific machine (and therefore it could produce a binary with a smaller execution time).

For my particular code (using `valgrind --tool=calgrind` and `perf stat`) I found that `-march=native` doesn't generate the smallest running time.

Now, my question is:

> if for my specific code I have found that the optimal binary (I mean, binary which produces faster execution time) is generated using `-Os` and/or `-O2`, this will be optimal in other machines?.

I would like to determine the optimal optimization flags in only one computer, but I have to run in different machines (someone with MacOS, other with Linux, and all of them with OS-versions different).

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or idea.

Comment: By 'optimal' I mean a faster code. Really I don't care the executable size, only I pay attention about it because in some situations this could produce also a faster code as [this @adn 's  answer points out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31813594/783646)

Comment: @ross I edit my question already

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL:DR**: No, different CPUs like different things.  Auto-vectorization could be a win on one machine but a loss on another, if the compiler was only able to do it inefficiently.

`gcc -O2 -march=native` or `gcc -O3 -march=native` are good options to try.  Or better, those + link-time optimization and/or profile-guided optimization so the compiler knows which loops are hot, and which branches usually only go one way vs. which branches are unpredictable.

IDK if you ever tried `gcc -march=native` without a `-O` option, but that won't be useful; `-march=native` with the default `-O0` will still be garbage.

---

`-O3` is worth trying.  The clang man-page says it can sometimes make code larger, so be careful with it, and benchmark to make sure your code really is faster.  It's only a "risk" as far as performance, not correctness.  The compiler won't bend the language rules without other options to specifically enable unsafe optimizations.

Clang docs say `-O4` is currently equivalent to `-O3`

At least for gcc, auto-vectorization is only enabled at `-O3`.  Clang probably has other good stuff that only happens at `-O3`.

I'm not sure whether the "general use" recommendation is still only `-O2`, or if `-O3` is generally conservative enough to be used all the time.  With `-fprofile-generate` / `-fprofile-use`, the compiler should avoid bloating the code size for infrequently-run paths, and only unroll loops that are actually hot.

If `perf` shows any I-cache misses, then `-Os` is worth trying.  Maybe `-Os` for most of your source files, and `-O3` for the source file with your hottest function.

`clang -O3` does some loop unrolling, but `gcc -O3` doesn't enable loop unrolling without `-fprofile-use` (or `-funroll-loops`, of course).

There's also `-Ofast`, which enables potentially unsafe optimizations.  If your code still works correctly with that, go for it.  (I think `unsafe` mostly means might overflow differently.  For FP code, if you don't care exactly how your code behaves if there's a NaN / Inf, or about exact order of operations, then you can use `-Ofast` (or just `-O3 -ffast-math`).

My list of things to test would absolutely include, if I wanted to spend some time finding optimal options for compiling something that I was going to spend a lot of CPU time running:

- `clang -O3 -march=native`
- `clang -O3 -march=native -fprofile-use`  (after `... -fprofile-generate`)
- the above with `-flto -emit-llvm` (**link-time optimization**, for whole-program optimization: inlining functions between source files (or at least seeing if they have side-effects or not, even if not inlined).)  gcc has `-flto` too.
- `gcc -O3 -march=native -fno-stack-protector -fprofile-use`
- the above with `-ffast-math` or even `-Ofast`

I guess `-Os` is worth trying, too.  Quirks of alignment can help, even if I-cache / uop-cache misses aren't a problem.

If `-fomit-frame-pointer` isn't the default in your compiler, use that, too, to free up an extra integer register and shorten function prologue/epilogue.

If you want to use the same binary on all machines, then `-march=some_baseline -mtune=something`.  (Assuming clang shares gcc's arch/tune options.)

Or just `-msse4.2 -mtune=sandybridge` or something.  As long as you're building an x86-64 binary, only the new SSE instructions are of interest to the compiler, I think.  (not popcnt, BMI, etc.)

The alternative is having a source checkout in your home directory on every machine, and building your program with the local compiler.  But if you have a really new version of gcc or clang, or intel's compiler, on one machine, then it can make sense to just use that.

You might also look into auto-parallelization: `gcc -ftree-parallelize-loops=n`, where `n` is the number of threads to use.

---

**The caveat to all this** is that I've heard of code breaking with `-O3` because it depended on behaviour not required by the language rules.  So aggressive optimization found a way to optimize in a way that made the code not do the same thing anymore.  If you want your code to run fast, make sure you avoid undefined behaviour so you can turn the optimizer all the way up.  (IIRC, there was a recent question about checking when the compiler optimized something based on assuming something because undefined behaviour would happen otherwise.)

Comment: +1 very fair point: optimization levels are not changing anything to the langage, they can just make some undefined behaviours in the codebase more *observable*.

Comment: That's true for `-O3`.  `-Ofast` may possibly do things that lead to integer overflow where there otherwise wouldn't have been any.  Any non-standards-compliant options are always documented as such in gcc and clang manuals, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually pointing to the answer yourself:

> The recommended optimization flag is -O2, although in certain cases -Os

We just need to add that this variation is not only due to the source-code (one code base giving better results with -Os, the other giving better results with -O2), but to the very machine the code is running on.

Imagine different processors for the same instruction set (no need to recompile). One could have a small cache, an -Os would then produce smaller executable, avoiding a lot of cache misses that could ruin the performances with -O2. The second processor as a huge cache, so it does not have so much cache misses when the code is compiled with -O2, then allowing the code to run faster in the -O2 case.

This is of course just a naively simplified example, I imagine the combination of parameters in real world to be quite daunting. But it gives you a hint why it is very hard to determine the optimal compilation in advance.

What some projects are doing is: they compile with different target binary sizes and instruction-set extensions, and then try to determine which actual binary to run when the application loads (by first poking around at the execution platform properties, to make an educated guess).

Comment: Thanks @AdN. Your answer confirms my main idea. But I would like if you could improve your answer (maybe in another answer) about the compilation with different target size and instruction-set extensions and determine which binary to run?. I don't know how achieve that

Comment: @Bruce_Warrier If the answer helps, upvotes are appreciated ; ) Sadly, I do not have enough knowledge to address the improvement you recommend. Perhaps it could be a good topic for another question ?

Comment: Certainly your right @adn. Your comment answer my asked question. I upvote your answer and I have accepted your answer. I forget it just for a moment.

Comment: Hey @adn. I post the ralated question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814963/choose-a-c-binary-according-to-the-enviroment/31815283#31815283) to try to get the improvement that I told you in a previous comment. Please feel free to enrich my question following the guidelines that you propose to me (if you consider that I have not caught your idea)

Comment: Don't ignore `-O3`.  It's worth trying.