# Choose a C binary according to the enviroment

Tags: c++, c, compilation, conditional-compilation

I have compiled my code with specific flags (-Os, -O2, -march=native and their combinations) in order to produce a faster execution time.

But my problem is that I don't run always in the same machine (because in my lab there are several different machines). Sometimes I run within a MacOS, or within a Linux (in both cases with different OS versions).

I wonder if there is a way to determine which binary will be run depending on the environment where the binary will run (I mean cache size, cpu cores, and other properties about the specific machine)?. In other words, how to choose (when the program loads) the faster binary (previously compiled with different target binary sizes and instruction-set extensions) according to the specific machine used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do dictionary with all the machine fingerprint and the binary name. But I wonder if the potential improvement in speed you may get is worth the trouble.

Comment: Sorry @rodrigo, but I didn't understand this sentence `Do dictionary with all the machine fingerprint and the binary name`. And yes, the improvement could be significant ,  due I'm using Sotf-Sphere Molecular Dynamics simulations.  In fact,  improvement in speed up could mean that the execution time may be reduced on the order of days

Comment: What I meant is: build all the binaries you need, but name them differently; then write a script/program that checks the machine, selects the right program and `exec()`s it.

Comment: Just have to ask - have you considered using a Linux virtual machine on the Apple machine? It'll likely be a bit slower than native execution, but if your Linux and Apple machines are both x86-64, the hardware virtualization features will likely keep the slowdown to a minimum.

Comment: @tonysdg your suggestion could able to use a unique executable (created  by choosing specific -O flags in order to get an optimal binary for the tested machine) in all computer, but probably I will get better results compiling in each machine with `-O2 -march=native`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may prebuilt a bunch of executables and choose one according to environment variable or things like `uname`. A Better approach to the problem is choose a toolchain that is able to perform JIT, install-time optimization and/or runtime optimization, like llvm.

Answer (score 4):

What you're talking about is called a **fat binary** (not FAT, the acronym).  From Wikipedia<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary)</sup>:

> A fat binary (or multiarchitecture binary) is a computer executable program which has been expanded (or "fattened") with code native to multiple instruction sets which can consequently be run on multiple processor types. This results in a file larger than a normal one-architecture binary file, thus the name.

At quick glance, there doesn't seem to be much support for it (see [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274846/why-arent-fat-binaries-more-widely-used-for-cross-platform-applications) from the Programmer StackExchange for more information).  Apple implemented this briefly when transitioning from PowerPC to Intel, but it doesn't seem to have been explored much since then.

Technically, fat binaries refer to a single binary that could run on multiple architectures...but I imagine the premise would hold for a single binary that runs on multiple OSes. And it comes back to the point Bizkit made in his/her/zir answer - generally, you compile your source code for the environment that you're in ahead of time.

Comment: I up-vote your answer because it provides another way to solve the problem. But as you suggest *fat binary* aren't the practical way to do that. The link provided by yourself explains the point  very well and in a straightforward form.

Comment: @Bruce_Warrior I apologize for not presenting a better answer - I'm unaware of one, unfortunately, but I figured this might present some useful information. For what it's worth, I up-voted and favorited your question as I'm interested to see the answer :)

Comment: The Intel compiler creates fat binaries as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just recompile your source code on each machine? Compilers are already written and optimized exactly for this kind of stuff. Simply recompile your source code on that machine architecture and you'll have a binary that runs just fine on that machine.

Comment: Doesn't help with cache size or number of cores.

Comment: Yes but the only thing that helps with number of cores is to actually write some mult-threaded code yourself; no script or compiler will do that for you. Serial code will run on a single core no matter what. As for cache sizes, aren't compilers written to optimize for cache sizes in the form of packing/aligning structures?

Comment: What ass-backwards compiler would optimize based on the hardware it runs on? Information about the target architecture and feature set desired are passed to the compiler by the developer.

Comment: AFAIK, compilers currently don't restructure programs on the level of blocking/tiling loops for cache size.  That's still a source-level optimization only.  ATLAS (a matrix math library) runs some benchmarks in its build system to find cache properties and choose optimal sizes for the machine it's being compiled on.  http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/  Point is, I'm not aware of any gcc/clang features that could take advantage of knowing cache properties.

Comment: @Bizkit I could recompile the code in each machine, but I would like to find the optimal compilation to each machine as I asked. I read that benchmark  depends on machine, SO, compilers and even compiler-versions, so is a tedious job have to identify the better optimizations in each machine. But apparently the straightforward way is to compile,  in order to produce safe and faster executions, is with `-O2 -march=native` flags (whatever gcc or clang). In this form I don't have to check handy  in each machine all possible -O optimization and their permutations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code tuned for the cache size of the machine you run on, check out the way [Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software (ATLAS)](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) does it.  When you compile it, it runs some tests to find what size to use for cache-blocking its loops, and puts that in a header file.